# Bootstrap Inline Elements

Tags: html, graphics, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

So at the top of my page I have a title and a facebook logo. Here's a working example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbgz/)

So everything is in a neat row at the top of the page. However, I want the logo and the text `Join us on...` to be on the right side, and the heading stays where it is. I've tried adding `class="pull-right"` to the 2nd and 3rd `<li>` elements, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/DGbgz/1/). But you can see how that really screws up the vertical alignment. Other than the alignment that's how I want it to look.

Any ideas on how to fix the alignment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the **pull-right** on the `li`. Also, H4 will cause a break so, you should put the img and "Join Us..." inside the H4.

Try this:

```
<ul class="inline">
  <li><h3 class="muted">Heading</h3></li>
  <li class="pull-right">
    <div class="media">
      <h4 class="media-heading">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://cache.boston.com/universal/site_graphics/facebook/facebook_logo_36x36.png" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Join us on Facebook" />
        </a>    
        Join Us on Facebook
      </h4>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the vertical alignment is still a little messed up

Answer (score -1):

you should add another  element and give it "pull-right" class. Your join us code should be in that .

So you should have like this;

```
<ul>
   logo
</ul>
<ul class="pull-right">
   join us
</ul>
```

Comment: this definitely did not work, it put everything in a new row. I need all three items (heading, logo, text) to be all in one row